# Implementing pagination in working query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I am connecting to a `SQL SERVER 2012` with 3 linked servers on it. I'm using premade queries to fetch data, but the person who made the queries did not implemented pagination which I'm gonna need so I'm trying to impelment this featuer. One thing to notice is that I don't know the version of the linked servers. It's may very first time using linked servers so I'm not familiar with the way they works but since on my machine I have 2012 version I tried using `OFFSET` and `FETCH` but got erros for invalid token. Then I was suggested to try the syntax that worked on my local `SQL SERVER 2008R2` but I can't do this too so, here it is. First the code that is working :

```
select *
from openquery(linkedServer,
'
select 
  ORG.Id as ID,  
  ORG.FirstName AS "FirstName",
  ORG.LastName as LastName

from YMFK.LK99Z ORG 

left outer join YMFK.LK88Z Phone
  ON ORG.Number = Phone.Number
    AND Phone.Col = ''something'' AND Phone.Col = ''else''
inner join YMFK.L77Z ORL
    ON ORG.Id = ORL.Id 
where 
ORG.FirsName  like ''%Peter%'''
)
```

Sorry for the modified names but the logic remains untouched so I think it wont be a problem.

So then I try to add pagination like so :

```
from  (SELECT tbl.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS
       rownum FROM YMFK.LK99Z as tbl WHERE ORG.FirstName  like ''%Peter%'' ) ORG
       WHERE ORG.rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

which i put on the place of `from YMFK.LK99Z ORG` and also removing `where 
    ORG.FirsName  like ''%Peter%'''`. This code is something i tried to get form a working pagination query modfying it as little as possible, but the first(original) query is working, and the second(modified) query is giving me error

`Column qualifier or table ORG undefined.".`

Answer (score 1):

in your code:

```
from  (SELECT tbl.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS
       rownum FROM YMFK.LK99Z as tbl WHERE ORG.FirstName  like ''%Peter%'' ) ORG
       WHERE ORG.rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

the alias `ORG` is defined outside the inner scope.
try the following:

```
from  (SELECT tbl.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS
       rownum FROM YMFK.LK99Z as tbl WHERE tbl.FirstName  like ''%Peter%'' ) ORG
       WHERE ORG.rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: I didn't get immediate error as before but after like 2-3secs I get this error - `Function not supported for query.".`

Comment: what happen when you run the very same query on the remote server directly?

Comment: I am running them on the remote server. Right now I'm using `Ms SQL Management studio` and execute each query directly.

Comment: what happens if you run the inner query only, the one with row_number? is that piece of code working ok?

Comment: yeap... if I remove the `Joins` and everything after the `Row_number` I'm getting results.. any idea what's going on?